# Alterar conteúdo de um input através de um botão

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante em programação e estou desenvolvendo um mini projeto de calculadora a fim de estudos. Decidi implementar um botão de apagar para limpar o visor, mas não consigo fazer ele funcionar de jeito nenhum.

parte HTML referente ao display

```
        <div class="visor">
            <input type="text" name="display" id="display">
            <input type="button" value="C" class='clear'id='clear' onclick="clear()">
        </div>
```

parte do JS

```
function clear() { document.getElementById('display').value = ' '; }
```

eu ultilizei desta mesma abordagem para escrever o número no display e funciona perfeitamente, mas para apagar não, como posso estar resolvendo isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito ser pq `clear` é uma palavra reservada. Veja que trocando `clear()` por `clearx()` funciona.

```js
function clearx() { 
 document.getElementById('display').value = ''; 
}
```

```html
<div class="visor">
 <input type="text" name="display" id="display">
 <input type="button" value="C" class='clear' id="clear" onclick="clearx()">
</div>
```

Veja `Set.prototype.clear()` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/clear

---

**DICA**

Talvez essa não seja a melhor opção para o seu caso, mas vc pode usa um `input` do tipo `reset` para limpar o formulário. Se vc trocar a `div` por `form` e colocar dentro um `input type="reset"` quando vc clicar nele ele limpa todos os `input` dentro do `form`

```html
<form class="visor">
 <input type="text" name="display" id="display">
 <input type="reset" value="C">
</form>
```

Comment: Toma meu +1 por ter aconselhado `<button type="reset">`.. É pra isso que ele foi inventado, tem que usar mesmo!

Comment: @fernandosavio valeu a força jovem, acho que o único inconveniente do type reset eh que vc não controla quais inputs ele apaga, se tiver 10 input ele apaga tudo... Mesmo problema acontece no CSS com o focus-within, qq input que focar dentro do form já ativa a classe... 

Comment: O reset é do form, então é pra ser assim mesmo.. :D